# Why does `1i.to_i` raise `RangeError` instead of `NoMethodError`?

Tags: ruby

`NoMethoError` is raised by `to_i` simply because the class doesn't have the method:

```
[].to_i # >> NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for []:Array)
```

Surely enough, `1i` has the method `to_i` and `to_f`, so it responds to them. But in reality this looks very tricky.

```
1i.respond_to?(:to_i) # => true
1i.to_i # >> RangeError (can't convert 0+1i into Integer)
```

From where does the `Range` class come in here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Surely enough, 1i has the method .to_i and .to_f so it responds to them. But in reality this looks very tricky!

Yes, it responds to them.  And when you invoke `to_i` on the complex literal `1i`, that method throws a `RangeError`.  That has nothing to do with the `Range` class; it is telling you that although `1i` has a `to_i` method from class `Complex`, its specific value is not one for which a meaningful result can be obtained.

Or to put it another way, that's what [`Complex::to_i`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Complex.html#method-i-to_i) *does* when invoked on an object whose imaginary part is nonzero or even inexact:

> **to_i → integer**
>
> Returns the value as an integer if possible (the imaginary part should
>   be exactly zero).
>
> ```
> Complex(1, 0).to_i    #=> 1
> Complex(1, 0.0).to_i  # RangeError
> Complex(1, 2).to_i    # RangeError
> ```

A `RangeError` communicates roughly that an argument is outside the range of the function to which it was provided, i.e. in the mathematical sense of "range".  `Complex` is a bit unusual in applying that sense of "range" to the target object, as opposed to a method argument, but it nevertheless makes sense.

Comment: From the docs for [`RangeError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/RangeError.html): _"Raised when a given numerical value is out of range."_

Answer (score 2):

What the documentation says is

```
Returns the value as an integer if possible (the imaginary part should be exactly zero).
```

So it doesn't look too useful, it works just if `i` is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The specification for `Complex#to_i` is as Ursus and John Bolinger say in their answer.

The reason `Complex#to_i` is defined (and hence does not raise a `NoMethoError` error) is because it returns the calculated value when the imaginary part is non-zero, and hence it needs to be defined. You can't raise a `NoMethodError` for just certain instances of a class.

The reason it does not raise a more familiar exception, say `ArgumentError`, is because it is not an argument, it is the receiver.

To raise an error for certain instances of a class, the best fit happened to be `RangeError`; there is no other `Exception` class that seems to fit better.